# Expand the groups space by clicking on the background or space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
The title space or title's background (please take a look at the picture with blue line) that is "Collapsible Group 1", "Collapsible Group 2" och "Collapsible Group 3". When I click on it should expand.

Problem:
Today, you click on the text only in order to expand the group. I would like to space around the text Collapsible Group 1", "Collapsible Group 2" och "Collapsible Group 3" to be clickable.

I don't know how to do it.

Info:
*I'm using bootstrap v.3 for this accordian.

```
jsbin.com/vuyuwaduba/edit?html,output
```

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change toggler element from anchor to `.panel-heading`

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
      Collapsible Group 1
   </h4>
</div>
```

and add some styling

```
.panel-heading.collapsed {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Working example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qibutaroha/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have another complementary, is it possible to not to show the pointer when you despand the groups title and its background?

Comment: @What'sUP do you mean to not show the pointer when its "exapaned"?

Comment: it is okej to show the ponter when it is about to expand. when you have expanded and you want go from despanded to expanded, then the pointer should be visible.

Comment: @What'sUP change css selector then. I updated answer and jsbin